# Why is the transconductance of a BJT greater than that of a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, bjt

During my classroom lectures, I came across this doubt of why the transconductance (\$g_m\$) of a BJT is greater than that of a MOSFET, i.e.:

$$g_{m(BJT)} > g_{m(MOSFET)}$$

It would be very helpful if anyone could clarify my doubt.

Comment: Because gm(bjt) = 2I/Vth while gm(mosfet) = 2I/Vov where I is the bias current, Vth is 0.025V at room temperature and Vov is the mosfet overdrive voltage. The overdrive voltage must be approximately 0.1-0.2V in order to operate in strong inversion. So the bjt has an higher transconductance than the mosfet for the same current. For a mosfet in weak inversion the argument is different, but it can be shown that the transconductance will still be lower

Comment: See: G.3.4 of [Appendix G: Comparison of the MOSFET and the BJT](https://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/fdscontent/uscompanion/us/static/companion.websites/9780199339136/Appendices/Appendix_G.pdf). It's written well.

Comment: @Lelesquiz there may be more to say, and you may not have the time, but that may be the closest this question gets to an answer and it does appear to be complete.  Could you repost as an answer?

Comment: @Jonk thanks for the document, would you mind telling me what it's Appendix G *of*?  I could probably benefit from reading the rest.  Ah much obliged!  I won't make a separate comment as this one hasn't expired.

Comment: @KH Microelectronic Circuits, sedra and smith, 7th edition, end of 2014, or early 2015 if I recall.